# SQL Reporting Services cannot configure virtual directories

Tags: sql-server, tfs, reporting-services, directory, virtual

I have an issue where we tried to upgrade our TFS 2005 server to 2008. During the install we encountered the error that it could not configure SQL Reporting Services. The log files showed that during the creation/configuration of the virtual directories for SQL Reporting Services (the Reports directory to be exact) a FileNotFoundException was thrown. The directory was actually created. SQL Reporting services were running just fine before the install. I tried to go in and reconfigure manually with the report server configuration tool but while it will create both directories, it still fails with a FileNotFoundException. I manually configure the .config files to point to the current server and I am able to get the sql report services web site running. We tried several things: messing with permissions, application pools, reinstalling the .NET framework, aspnet_regiis, etc. but nothing has changed the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered a similar problem. After installing a new RS instance and applying SQL Server sp2 and the KB954606 hotfix, I attempted to configure the RS instance, but creating the virtual directory failed. As in your case, the virtual directory was created, but the RS configuration tool threw an error.

In my case, deleting the newly-created virtual directory using IIS manager and then rebooting the server fixed everything. I was able to successfully create the virtual directories using RS Configuration Tool following the reboot.